# How do I configure nginx to use redis instead of local disk with proxy_cache and proxy_cache_use_stale?

Tags: nginx, proxypass, redis

I'd like to set up a reverse proxy to a REST service that uses HTTPS.  The proxy needs to store cached responses in redis (not on disk).  If the REST service is down or times out, I want the proxy to serve stale data from redis.

The suite of proxy_cache directives in nginx seems to be exactly what I need.  I got it to work beautifully, except it stores the cached files on disk.  I want to use a redis store instead.  I've looked into SR cache, but this seems to not provide features like proxy_cache_use_stale.

How do I get the best of both worlds?  Am I going about this all wrong?